# Initialize struct with fields using closure

Tags: struct, rust, closures

It's possible to initialize a tuple struct `A` or enum `B` by passing the constructor as a closure parameter to the `wrap` function.

This doesn't work for struct `D`, which has named field `x`:

```
fn wrap<A, B, F>(item: A, f: F) -> B
where
    F: Fn(A) -> B,
{
    f(item)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A<T>(T);

#[derive(Debug)]
enum B<T> {
    C(T),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct D<T> {
    x: T,
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", wrap(1, A)); // prints A(1)
    println!("{:?}", wrap(1, B::C)); // prints C(1)
    // println!("{:?}", wrap(1, D)); // sounds good, doesn’t work
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f6ff6dea234ea5f7936f2b5f14e7a241&version=stable)

Is it possible to somehow make it work for structs with named fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'structs without named fields' aren't exactly structs but tuple structs. Whereas the name of a tuple struct can be used the same way as a function name, it isn't true for a struct name. Using the struct name to instantiate one struct, you have to specify the name of the parameters:

```
println!("{:?}", wrap(1, |i|(D { x: i }))); // doesn't sound good, but works
```

Comment: Even shorter: `wrap(1, |x| D {x})`

Comment: Apparently enum variants with named data like this `enum A<T> { B { x: T } }` needs to be initialized the same way.